# Replace item in NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitextfield

I have an NSMutablearray that I have data saved to. Data is input on my main ViewController. When you tap on a saved item, the SecondViewController has a textfield that the data entry is loaded into in order to be edited. I want to be able to edit that item and then save it back to the array.

I am fairly new to Objective-C / Cocoa Touch so please go easy on me.

```
- (ToDoItem *) updateToDoItem: (ToDoItem *) todoitem {
    NSLog(@"ToDoItemSvc.updateToDoItem: %@", [todoitem description]);
    NSMutableArray *toDoItems = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *todoitem in toDoItems) {
            if ([[ToDoItem] isEqualToString:toDoItems]) {
        [toDoItems replaceObjectAtIndex:todoitem];
    }
}
```

I know this isnt completely correct and may be completely off base but Im hoping I am moving in the right direction with this.

#### EDIT

Here is my ToDoItemSvcArchive.m file

```
#import "ToDoItemSvcArchive.h"

@implementation ToDoItemSvcArchive

NSString *filePath;

NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

- (id) init {
    NSArray *dirPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"ToDoItems.archive"]];
    [self readArchive];
    return self;
}

    - (void) readArchive {
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
{
        toDoItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: filePath];
}
    else
{
        toDoItems = [NSMutableArray array];
}
}

- (void) writeArchive {
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toDoItems toFile:filePath];

}

- (ToDoItem *) createToDoItem: (ToDoItem *) todoitem {
    NSLog(@"ToDoItemSvc.createToDoItem: %@", [todoitem description]);

    [toDoItems addObject:todoitem];
    [self writeArchive];

    return todoitem;
}


- (NSMutableArray *) retrieveAllToDoItems {
    return toDoItems;
}

- (ToDoItem *) updateToDoItem: (ToDoItem *) todoitem {
    NSLog(@"ToDoItemSvc.updateToDoItem: %@", [todoitem description]);
    NSMutableArray *toDoItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *todoitem in toDoItems) {
        if ([[ToDoItem] isEqualToString:toDoItems]) {
            [toDoItems replaceObjectAtIndex:todoitem];
        }
    }

   // return todoitem;
}

- (ToDoItem *) deleteToDoItem: (ToDoItem *) todoitem {
    NSLog(@"ToDoItemSvc.deleteToDoItem: %@", [todoitem description]);

    [toDoItems removeObject:todoitem];
   [self writeArchive];

    return todoitem;
}

@end
```

#### EDIT

I guess what I dont really understand is how to get the actual index of the object that needs to be replaced.

#### Edit

I think this is better

```
- (ToDoItem *) updateToDoItem: (ToDoItem *) todoitem {
    NSLog(@"ToDoItemSvc.updateToDoItem: %@", [todoitem description]);
    NSUInteger index = [toDoItems indexOfObject:todoitem];
    [toDoItems replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:todoitem];

    return todoitem;
}
```

Im still not sure how to specify the correct index.

Comment: `[[ToDoItem] isEqualToString:toDoItems]` what the what? neither the receiver nor the toDoItems is an NSString!!!??? Show the code where you "load" the todoItem into the TextField. And where does the ToDoItem itself come from?

Comment: This... `NSMutableArray *toDoItems = [NSMutableArray array];` ...creates a new empty array.  Your next line tries to find things inside the array.  It's not going to happen.

Comment: 1) The code you posted won't even compile. 2) You create a new empty array and then try to iterate through its objects - but it is and always will be empty. What's the point? 3) There are three mistakes just on the `if` statement line. 4) The call to `replaceObjectAtIndex:` isn't valid. It's missing one of the parameters. 5) This seems to be a similar mess to the `updateToDoItem` method in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541590/updating-data-object-using-archiving-nsmutablearray) which you never replied back to.

Comment: I went ahead and removed my previous post.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of replacing an object here.  It doesn't seem as if you want a different `ToDoItem` but only a change to some information about an existing one.  (?)  For example, you say, "edit that item and then save it back to the array," but there's no need to "save it back" if it hasn't been removed.

Comment: Then perhaps I am totally missunderstanding how this should work

Answer (score 0):

Over complicating the entire thing

Changed todoitemtext to todoitemobject and made it a todoitem rather than an NSString. Now when I click update, it updates the object and when you go back to the list, the view calls reloaddata and the view is updated with the new object

```
- (IBAction)updateToDoItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"updatingToDoItem: entering");
    toDoItemObject.todoitem = toDoItem.text;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    toDoItem.text = toDoItemObject.todoitem;

}
```

Works like a champ now.